# Filter for all resources inside specified resource groups

Tags: azure, cloudcustodian

I'm trying to use cloud custodian to create a cleanup script for a playground environment. Each developer gets their own resource group (where they have contributor permissions), and can create any resources inside that resource group. I want to delete all resources inside each resource group weekly.

I noticed there is a [parent](https://cloudcustodian.io/docs/azure/resources/azure-common-filters.html#azure-common-filters-parent) filter available. So I tried to do something like this:

```
policies:
  - name: delete-playground-resources
    resource: azure.armresource
    filters:
      - type: parent
        filter:
          - type: value
            key: name
            op: regex
            value: '^myprefix*$'
```

But that produced a validation error:

> 2022-06-28 15:53:31,641: custodian.commands:ERROR invalid policy file:
> custodian.yml error: Failed to validate policy [{'type': 'value',
> 'key': 'name', 'op': 'regex', 'value': '^myprefix*$'}] is not of type
> 'number'
>
> Failed validating 'type' in schema[0]:
> {'type': 'number'}
>
> On instance:
> [{'key': 'name',
> 'op': 'regex',
> 'type': 'value',
> 'value': '^myprefix*$'}]   {'name': 'delete-playground-resources', 'resource': 'azure.armresource',
> 'filters': [{'type': 'parent', 'filter': [{'type': 'value', 'key':
> 'name', 'op': 'regex', 'value': '^myprefix*$'}]}]} is not valid under
> any of the given schemas

I'm guessing the `parent` filter isn't supported on the type `azure.armresource` (especially since it's not listed [here](https://cloudcustodian.io/docs/azure/resources/armresource.html#filters)).

If it is supported, what am I doing wrong?
If it's not supported, how else can I get ALL resources inside specific resource groups?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the [documentation](https://cloudcustodian.io/docs/azure/resources/armresource.html#filters) , Adding **parent** filter in the `azure.armresource`is not applicable. You can find the llist of supported filters below:

[image]

Instead of using **parent** filter , you can make use of any one of above mentioned filters.

To delete the resource based on **value** filter, you can use the below policy by giving name as resource in value.

```
policies:
  -  name:  delete-resources
  resource:  azure.armresource
  description:  |
  Deletes any ARM resource based on the name in value
  filters:
  -  type:  value
  key:  name
  value:  resource name
  op:  contains
  actions:
  -  type:  delete
```

**Reference:**
[Azure Common Actions — Cloud Custodian documentation](https://cloudcustodian.io/docs/azure/resources/azure-common-actions.html#azure-common-actions-delete)